# prettyPhoto for multiple galleries on one page

Tags: jquery, html, web, prettyphoto

I would like to initialize prettyPhoto plugin for multiple galleries on one page so they can be shown separately. My idea was to go through all the divs which contain pictures and initialize new `prettyPhoto` for all images in that div. But `val` is apparently some kind of object and I am not able to call any functions on it. Is there a way how to do what I need?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $.each($(".gallery"), function(i, val) {
         $(val).find("img").prettyPhoto({}); //init prettyPhoto plugin
     });
 });
```

P.S. Sorry for lame question I suppose it's basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution in case anybody is interested.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $.each($(".gallery"), function(i, val) {
            var queryString = ".gallery:nth(" + i + ") a[rel^='prettyPhoto']";
            $(queryString).prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'light_square', social_tools: false});
        });
    });
```